# Compiz hogging CPU after 2017-02-20 Software Update - (14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, updates, compiz, intel-graphics, mesa

After reboot following a software update via the Update Manager on Feb. 20, 2017, **compiz** has begun hogging CPU time (20-80%) when anything moves on the screen. Have tried the posted fixes, but no joy. I suspect (but cannot confirm) the problem has to do with one or more of the following:

```
  "linux-libc-dev-3.13.0-109-generic(3.13.0-109.156)"
  "linux-headers-3.13.0-109(3.13.0-109.156)"
  "linux-image-extra-3.13.0-109-generic(3.13.0-109.156)"
  "linux-headers-3.13.0-109-generic(3.13.0-109.156)"
  "linux-image-3.13.0-109-generic(3.13.0-109.156)"
```

Most of the other 10 updates loaded at the same time were "...109.117"

Unity desktop is extremely sluggish, to the point of being useless. Worked great prior to update.

Problem appeared to go away with the next update (Feb. 22), but returned after a subsequent reboot on Feb. 27.

Here's the data from `inxi -G`:
**Graphics Card:** Intel Mobile 945GM/GMS 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
**bus-ID:** 00:02.0
**X.Org:** 1.15.1
**driver:** intel
**Resolution:** 1280x800@60.0hz, 1152x720@60.0hz
**GLX Renderer:** Mesa DRI Intel 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
**GLX Version:** 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
**Direct Rendering:** Yes

Comment: You have my apologies, but I will not be voting to reopen this question:  This question as currently presented doesn't appear to reflect current conditions and as such it's **unclear what you are asking.** You have failed to bring the question up to date to include what happened between 2/22 (when your problem went away and 2/27 when it returned.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the system. I (and others, apparently) have been having recurring problems with **compiz** taking the CPU hostage. But I'm over that....loaded Cinnamon and have a functioning desktop again.